# Convert long date stored as text to short date Access SQL

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am trying to convert a long date stored as text to a short date via MS Access SQL.

For example I have a table which parsed information from a website and one of the field is Tuesday, June 17, 2014. I want to run an update query in another table which takes this value and converts it to 17/06/2014.

Any help on what functions I can use please?

thanks

Elton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @VBlades' example, but allowing the year to be different from 2014, assuming that other years might appear in the source data.

This will only work if the dates you wish to parse are formated consistently.

Paste this function into a vba module and call it from your query.

```
Function dateParser(datestr As String) As Variant
Dim day_month, year, day_month_year As String
day_month = Split(datestr, ",")(1) 
year = Split(datestr, ",")(2)
day_month_year = day_month + ", " + year 
dateParser = Format(day_month_year, "dd/mm/yyyy")  
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried @ako's example and it works!

Answer (score 2):

For date strings like "Tuesday, June 17, 2014" a VBA function like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ParseDateString(DateString As Variant) As Variant
    If IsNull(DateString) Then
        ParseDateString = Null
    Else
        ParseDateString = CDate(Split(DateString, ", ", 2)(1))
    End If
End Function
```

will convert the string to a true Date value. If you are running an update query and putting the resulting value into a `Date/Time` field in the table then you **DO NOT** want to convert the date to `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Just use the result of the function (the true Date value).

If you *must* convert the date to a string then use the unambiguous date format `yyyy-mm-dd`. If you convert to `dd/mm/yyyy` format, Access might mangle ambiguous dates and `12/06/2014` could be interpreted as December 6, *not* June 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Format(Split("Tuesday, June 17, 2014", ",")(1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks but it's giving me an error 'The expression you have entered has an invalid dot (.) or missing operator ...' I tried to juggle with the () to no success

Comment: There's not dot operator in this expression, so I would imagine the error is in your surrounding code.  If you post I can take a look.